# I cant create a new instance of BleManager using react-native-ble-plx

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

when i call the react-native-ble-plx package inside the code of App.js in my react-native proyect using the following code:

```
this.manager = new BleManager();
```

It throws the following error:

```
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_BleModule.BleModule.createClient')
    This error is located at:
    in DashboardScreen (at App.js:17)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
- node_modules/react-native-ble-plx/src/BleManager.js:91:14 in BleManager
* screens/DashboardScreen.js:15:19 in scanAndConnect
* screens/DashboardScreen.js:55:4 in render
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10563:21 in finishClassComponent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14091:21 in performUnitOfWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14129:41 in workLoop
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14226:15 in renderRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15193:17 in performWorkOnRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15090:24 in performWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15047:14 in performSyncWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14925:19 in requestWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14711:16 in scheduleWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15429:15 in scheduleRootUpdate
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16142:20 in render
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/renderApplication.js:59:52 in renderApplication
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:101:10 in run
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:195:26 in runApplication
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:349:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:106:26 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:297:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:105:17 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

And i already follow the steps of the documentation in https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx, so i dont know what is failing, please help! :(

Version of:

node v10.16.0

npm 6.9.0

expo ^32.0.0

expokit ^32.1.1

react-native-ble-plx 1.0.3

react-native-cli 2.0.1

react-native 0.57.1

UPDATE:

As a team we found the error is that expo wasn't compatible with react-native-ble-plx so we change to pure react-native (metro bundler). Be careful using expo!

Comment: Please provide the error stacktrace (at least with the line numbers). And no one should ever be declaring/assigning a variable like `let this.a = b`. It has either to be `this.a = b` or `let a = b`